# In hashmap how to assign previous key to the next if duplicate values are exist

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

Ii'm trying to assigning the previous key to the next in case of duplicate are present in hashmap.

for example, duplicate entries in hashmap:

```
5-->51  
6-->51
```

I want output as below:

```
5-->51  
5-->51
```

Below is my code:

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap();
    map.put(1, 99);
    map.put(2, 120);
    map.put(3, 89);
    map.put(4, 71);
    map.put(5, 51);
    map.put(6, 51);
    map.put(7, 77);
    map.put(8, 44);
    map.put(9, 22);
    Set set = new HashSet<>();
    List list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Entry<Integer, Integer> mapVal : map.entrySet()) {
        if (!set.add(mapVal.getValue())) {
            list.add(mapVal.getValue());
        } else {
            set.add(mapVal.getValue());
        }
    }
    for (Entry<Integer, Integer> mapVal : map.entrySet()) {
        if (list.contains(mapVal.getValue())) {
            System.out.println(mapVal.getKey() + "-->" + mapVal.getValue());
        }
    }
```

Would it be possible in hashmap case? If so, what algorithm or code should I use?

Comment: Before I write an answer I want to make sure that you realize a HashMap is an unordered structure.  You realize that, right?  So if you put values in an order they are not guaranteed to stay in that order?  I can think of reasons you would do something like this anyway, but I want to make sure you're using the right structure.

Comment: Please use generics.

Comment: yes i  know HashMap is an unordered structure.

Comment: You could not get such a thing with a Map as keys are unique.

Comment: @davidxxx I think that your comment would be an appropriate answer to this question. If you want to write it as an answer, it would be easier for others to find.

Comment: agreed but still if i want this kind of output,Is there any other way to do that.

Comment: @Keara I added it in an answer and I provided a workaround for the output.

Comment: You can't have duplicate keys, as others have mentioned, but you could just remove the duplicate values from the map if you don't want duplicates. Is that what you are trying to do?  Do you want to just print that output but not change the actual keys, or do you need to change the keys? Do you need to then have a duplicate key-value pair, or could you just have the one key-value pair and just get rid of any others with the same value? What exactly are you trying to use this for?

Comment: I can't really understand this question. Please clarify why you need this behavior and kindly explain your use case.

Comment: Note that any question that requests "please help me out with algorithm or sample code" is what we call a _request for free work_ or, in close-reason terms, _too broad_. I suggest you narrow this down a bit to a more specific question.

Answer (score 3):

If I got your question right. It's not possible to have duplicate keys in a map whichever map it is. You want for two value same key which isn't possible.

Answer (score 1):

> i want output as below:

```
5-->51
5-->51
```

You could not get such a thing with a Map as keys are unique.

As workaround to get that result in the output, you  should use a `Map` implementation that maintains the insertion order of the elements: `LinkedHashMap`.
`HashMap` doesn't maintain it.

Then the idea is rather simple :

- Create a list from map keys and create another list from map values.
- Iterate values list and update elements of the keys list which the value associated contains a value already encountered.
- output the lists

Here is a sample code :

```
public class Foo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put(1, 99);
        map.put(2, 120);
        map.put(3, 89);
        map.put(4, 71);
        map.put(5, 51); // 51 value
        map.put(6, 51); // 51 value
        map.put(7, 77);
        map.put(8, 51); // 51 value
        map.put(9, 22);

        List<Integer> keys = new ArrayList<>(map.keySet());
        List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<>(map.values());

        Set<Integer> valuesWithKeyUpdated = new HashSet<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < values.size() - 1; i++) {

            final Integer oldestKeyForCurrentValue = keys.get(i);
            final Integer currentValue = values.get(i);

            if (valuesWithKeyUpdated.contains(currentValue)) {
                continue;
            }

            for (int j = 1; j < values.size(); j++) {
                if (currentValue == values.get(j)) {
                    keys.set(j, oldestKeyForCurrentValue);
                }
            }

            valuesWithKeyUpdated.add(values.get(i));
        }


        for (int i = 0; i < keys.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("key=" + keys.get(i) + ", value="+ values.get(i));

        }
    }
}
```

> key=1, value=99
>
> key=2, value=120
>
> key=3, value=89
>
> key=4, value=71
>
> key=5, value=51 // value 51 with key 5 in the original map
>
> key=5, value=51 // value 51 : display 5 instead of 6
>
> key=7, value=77
>
> key=5, value=51 // value 51 : display 5 instead of 8
>
> key=9, value=22

Comment: i got it now what i expected even we know that duplicate keys are not allowed in hashmap.Actaully i need this requirement for making Bar chart  
 in PDF reports since bars varies depends upon billing units which i mapped with hashmap keys. 

Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: @Akash Lanjewar You are welcome :) If my answer makes sense, don't hesitate to upvote or accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @AliOmar62 you can not have duplicate keys in map.

What you can do is inverse key with value and collect all values to collection e.g.

```
    Map<Integer, List<Integer>> sameValueToDiffKeys = map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(e -> new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(e.getValue(), e.getKey()))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(SimpleImmutableEntry::getKey, e -> new ArrayList<>(Collections.singleton(e.getValue())), (first, second) -> {
                first.addAll(second);
                return first;
            }));
```

The output with your data will look in console like:

```
{51=[5, 6], 99=[1], 22=[9], 71=[4], 120=[2], 89=[3], 44=[8], 77=[7]}
```

Please take a look at merge function, which is the third argument to `Collectors.toMap`.

This function resolves all duplications for one key by merging them into one collection.